# Programatically start cmd with elevated rights

Tags: windows-10, command-line, elevation, nvm

I have a bunch of JavaScript applications which all require a different version of Node.js. I have installed `nvm for Windows` and now would like to automate the process of starting them all with one file.

I have tried to set up a `cmd` file, which looks like this:

```
cd AngularApp
if exist node_modules (start "Angular" cmd /c "nvm use 10.21.0 && npm start") else (start "Angular" cmd /c "nvm use 10.21.0 && npm i && npm start")
cd ../VueApp
if exist node_modules (start "Vue" cmd /c "nvm use 12.21.0 && npm start") else (start "Vue" cmd /c "nvm use 12.21.0 && npm i && npm start")
cd ../ReactApp
if exist node_modules (start "React" cmd /c "nvm use 14.16.0 && npm start") else (start "React" cmd /c "nvm use 14.16.0 && npm i && npm start")
cd ..
```

I can see three new command prompts open. However, `nvm` requires elevated access rights (i.e.: running the command prompt as an administrator), so I am then prompted 6 times (2 times per each new command prompt) to allow the app make changes to my device. This is quite annoying by itself, but then all three new windows are just killed and I have no apps running.

What is wrong with my script? How can I start my command prompts with elevated rights (in order to decrease the prompts I need to confirm)?

Note: if it is easier to achieve my goal with a `.bat` file, PowerShell script or via the Node.js command prompt, then I am happy to use a different tool.

Comment: Just save it as a .bat file and right click then select Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the actual issue in a different way: I have added `node` as a dependency into `package.json`. Both `npm` and `yarn` check `package.json` for `node`. If they find one, they will use that particular version of Node.js. If not, they will use the system-wide. Thus, `nvm` and command prompt with elevated user rights is not needed anymore.

However, I have also found an answer for starting and admin prompt:

**Starting a command prompt with elevated user rights**

It can be easily achieved by this `cmd` script:

```
powershell -command "start-process cmd -verb runas -argumentlist '/c npm -v && pause'"
```

What this does is:

1. `powershell -command` - use PowerShell to execute the desired command
2. `"start-process cmd"` - open up a new command prompt
3. `"-verb runas"` - give the command prompt elevated user rights
4. `"-argumentlist '/c npm -v && pause'"` - in the elevated command prompt, get the version of npm and then wait for user input

However, it might be tricky not to get lost in the nested strings. So you might want to directly create a Powershell script which opens an administrator command prompt:

```
Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "/c npm -v && pause"
```

The second script is essentially the same as the first one - but you are opening a command prompt directly from Powershell. Or, you might have a Powershell script which opens up another Powershell with elevated user rights:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs {cd $pwd; npm -v; Read-Host}
```

Here are a couple of small changes:

1. You can specify multiple commands for a new Powershell window in curly brackets and separate them by semicolon.
2. `cd $pwd` - ensures that the new window will navigate to the same path you are currently in. Otherwise, Powershell will probably open up in `C:\Windows\system32`
3. `npm -v` - gets the version of npm
4. `Read-Host` - waits for user input